# Make keyboard show below custom view in react-native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make a custom autocomplete view with TextInput from react-native-paper, I would like the ScrollView which has a list of suggestions below the TextInput to show above the keyboard, so the user can type and see suggestions while typing.

Code approached:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ScrollView, View, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Animated, findNodeHandle } from 'react-native'
import { TextInput, List, Text, Colors, Divider } from 'react-native-paper'
import theme from '../Theme';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';


export class AutocompleteTextInput extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props)
      this.state = {
          data: this.props.data != undefined? this.props.data : [{a: "aa"}, {a: "bb"}],
          query: this.props.query != undefined? this.props.query : "",
          label: this.props.label != undefined? this.props.label : "",
          showAutocomplete: true,
          keyboardVisible: true,
          found: ""
      }
      this.menu = null;
      this.paddingInput = new Animated.Value(0);
      this.keyboardPadding = new Animated.Value(0);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidShow", this.onKeyboardVisible.bind(this))
      this.keyboardDismissListener = Keyboard.addListener("keyboardDidHide", this.onKeyboardDismiss)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
      this.keyboardDismissListener.remove()
  }

  /*autoSuggest = () => {
   //   HereGeoService.getSuggessionsByQuery()
  }*/

  showAutocomplete = () => {
      this.setState({ showAutocomplete: true })
  }

  hideAutocomplete = () => {
      this.setState({ showAutocomplete: false })
  }


  onKeyboardVisible = (event) => {
    console.log("Keyboard: visible")
    this.setState({keyboardVisible: true, showAutocomplete: true})
    Animated.timing(this.paddingInput, {
        duration: 50,
        toValue: event.endCoordinates.height - (event.endCoordinates.height * 0.5)
    }).start()
  }

  onKeyboardDismiss = (event) => {
    console.log("Keyboard: dismissed")
    this.setState({keyboardVisible: false, showAutocomplete: false})
    Animated.timing(this.paddingInput, {
        duration: 50,
        toValue: 0
    }).start()
  }


  onValueChosen = () => {
      if(this.props.onValueChanged != undefined) {
        this.props.onValueChanged(this.state.found)
      }
  }

  search = async () => {
        /*if(this.props.searchFunc) {
           await this.props.searchFunc()
        }*/

  }

  render() {
    return (
       <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <KeyboardAvoidingView>
                    <ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled>
                        <TextInput onEndEditing={Keyboard.dismiss} mode="outlined" onChangeText={(K) => {
                                    console.log(K)
                                }} label={this.state.label}/>
                                {this.state.showAutocomplete == true?
                                    (<Animated.View style={{ height: 100, marginBottom: this.paddingInput }}>
                                        <ScrollView ref='list' overScrollMode="auto" nestedScrollEnabled={true} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                                            <List.Item style={{ color: theme.colors.primary }} onPress={ () => {}} title="aaaaa"></List.Item>
                                            <Divider></Divider>
                                            <List.Item style={{ color: theme.colors.primary }} onPress={ () => {}} title="aaaaa"></List.Item>
                                            <Divider></Divider>
                                            <List.Item style={{ color: theme.colors.primary }} onPress={ () => {}} title="bbbbb"></List.Item>
                                            <Divider></Divider>
                                        </ScrollView>
                                    </Animated.View>
                                    )
                                    :
                                    <View style={{ width: 0, height: 0 }}></View>
                                }
                    </ScrollView>
                </KeyboardAvoidingView>
       </View>
    )
  }
}

AutocompleteTextInput.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    query: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    data: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onValueChanged: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}
```

This is how keyboard shows when focusing on text input:

[image]

What I want to acheive (keyboard should show below the suggestion list):

[image]

Update:

I found the following solution, I tried to add padding when keyboard is shown, and reset padding to normal when keyboard is hidden but the problem is the solution works on snack and for both Android and iOS but not working on my phone or emulator in my side when changing paddingBottom view is not pushed above the keyboard:

https://snack.expo.io/rk8kQCuLE

Can someone tell me why it is not working in the emulator or in a device in my side? What could I have done wrong?

Comment: If you dont mind an extra library, this one does the work, https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: @wicky I already tried that library but did not work or maybe I did not know the right implementation. Can you please provide some guidance if it works?

Comment: Have you tried with `<KeyboardAwareScrollView>` as the outer most view? not within any other views

Comment: Yes I did, I even tried to add `extraHeight={100}` prop but no height added above the keyboard, so the suggestion list is hidden under the keyboard not shown above it.